# ReactJs onUserInput... Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am building a simple Todo ReactJs app. I made several attempts to attach the onUserInput event on input controls for edit mode, however get  the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:9:21230
    at Array.map (native)
    at b.value (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:9:21002)
    at http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:6:10
    at h (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:5:21688)
    at n._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:5:31989)
    at n._renderValidatedComponent (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:6:163)
    at n.performInitialMount (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:5:26759)
    at n.mountComponent (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:5:25548)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:3:18577)

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong??

Here is my code:

```
  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classNames from 'classnames';

export class ContactsListApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data
        }
        this.addContact = this.addContact.bind(this);
        this.deleteContact = this.deleteContact.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }
    updateContact(editContactObj) {
        var tmpStateData = this.state.data;
        var newStateData = Array.prototype.map.call(tmpStateData, function (contact, index) {

            if (contact.id == editContactObj.id) {
                contact = editContactObj;
            }
            return contact;
        });

        this.setState({
            data: newStateData
        })
    }
    addContact(newContactObj) {
        var tmpStateData = this.state.data;
        tmpStateData.push(newContactObj);

        this.setState({
            data: tmpStateData
        });
    }
    deleteContact(contactId) {
        const tmpStateData = this.state.data;
        var newContactsData = tmpStateData.filter(function (contact, index) {
            return contact.id != contactId;
        });

        this.setState({
            data: newContactsData
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <h3>
                        <i className="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Contact List
                    </h3>
                    <div className="contact-container">
                        <AddContactPanel addNewContact={this.addContact.bind(this)} />
                        <ContactListPanel contacts={this.state.data} deleteContact={this.deleteContact.bind(this)} updateContact={this.updateContact.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ContactsListApp.propTypes = {
    data : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}


class ContactListPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var delCont = this.props.deleteContact;
        var updCont = this.props.updateContact;
        var items = Array.prototype.map.call(this.props.contacts, function (contact, index) {

            return <ContactItem
                key={index}
                id={contact.id}
                name={contact.name}
                occupation={contact.occupation}
                email={contact.email}
                telephone={contact.telephone}
                deleteContact={delCont.bind(this)}
                updateContact={updCont.bind(this)}
                />
        });

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                        <table className="contact-list" summary="This table lists contacts added via the form above">
                            <thead className="contact-list__head">
                                <tr>
                                    <th className="col-sm-2">
                                        <h4>Fullname</h4>
                                    </th>
                                    <th className="col-sm-2">
                                        <h4>Occupation</h4>
                                    </th>
                                    <th className="col-sm-2">
                                        <h4>Email</h4>
                                    </th>
                                    <th className="col-sm-2">
                                        <h4>Telephone</h4>
                                    </th>
                                    <th className="col-sm-4">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {items}
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                {/*sort params*/}
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ContactListPanel.propTypes = {
    contacts : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}


class ContactItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
            inputValues: this.initialInputStates()
        };
    }
    initialInputStates() {
        return {
            "id": this.props.id,
            "name": this.props.name,
            "occupation": this.props.occupation,
            "email": this.props.email,
            "telephone": this.props.telephone
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.cancelEditContactMode();
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
            inputValues: this.initialInputStates()
        };
    }
    componentWillUnMount() {
        this.cancelEditContactMode();
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
            inputValues: this.initialInputStates()
        };
    }
    handleUpdateData(e) {
        var updateObj = {
            "id": this.state.inputValues.id,
            "name": this.state.inputValues.name,
            "occupation": this.state.inputValues.occupation,
            "email": this.state.inputValues.email,
            "telephone": this.state.inputValues.telephone
        }
        this.props.updateContact(updateObj);

        this.cancelEditContactMode();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    handleDeleteContact(e) {
        var contactId = this.refs.contactId.value;
        this.props.deleteContact(contactId);

        e.preventDefault();
    }
    cancelEditContactMode() {
        this.setState({
            editMode: false,
            inputValues: this.initialInputStates()
        });
    }
    applyEditContactMode() {
        this.setState({
            editMode: true,
            inputValues: this.initialInputStates()
        });
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            editMode: true,
            inputValues: {
                "id": this.props.id,
                "name": (event.target === this.refs.emContactName) ? event.target.value : this.refs.emContactName.value,
                "occupation": (event.target === this.refs.emContactOccupation) ? event.target.value : this.refs.emContactOccupation.value,
                "email": (event.target === this.refs.emContactEmail) ? event.target.value : this.refs.emContactEmail.value,
                "telephone": (event.target === this.refs.emContactTelephone) ? event.target.value : this.refs.emContactTelephone.value
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        var classes = ['contact-list__item', { 'contact-list__item--outdoor': this.props.isOutdoor }];
        var styles = {
            showEditDisplay: {
                "display": this.state.editMode ? 'block' : 'none'
            }, 
            hideEditDisplay: { 
                "display" : !this.state.editMode ? 'block' : 'none'
            }
        }
        return (
            <tr className={classNames(classes)}>
                <td className="col-sm-3">
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} style={styles.showEditDisplay} className="form-control" ref="emContactName" type="text" value={this.state.inputValues.name} />
                    <label style={styles.hideEditDisplay}>{this.props.name}</label>
                </td>
                <td className="col-sm-2">
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} style={styles.showEditDisplay} className="form-control" ref="emContactOccupation" type="text" value={this.state.inputValues.occupation} />
                    <label style={styles.hideEditDisplay}>{this.props.occupation}</label>
                </td>
                <td className="col-sm-2">
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} style={styles.showEditDisplay} className="form-control" ref="emContactEmail" type="text" value={this.state.inputValues.email} />
                    <label style={styles.hideEditDisplay}>{this.props.email}</label>
                </td>
                <td className="col-sm-2">
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} style={styles.showEditDisplay} className="form-control" ref="emContactTelephone" type="text" value={this.state.inputValues.telephone} />
                    <label style={styles.hideEditDisplay}>{this.props.telephone}</label>
                </td>
                <td className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="contactId" ref="contactId" value={this.state.inputValues.id} />

                    <div className="editMode" style={styles.showEditDisplay}>
                        <button className="btn btn-default icon btn-info" onClick={this.handleUpdateData.bind(this)} >
                            <i className="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Update
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-default icon btn-info" onClick={this.cancelEditContactMode.bind(this)}>
                            <i className="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="nonEditMode" style={styles.hideEditDisplay}>
                        <button className="btn btn-default icon btn-danger" onClick={this.handleDeleteContact.bind(this)} >
                            <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-default icon btn-warning" onClick={this.applyEditContactMode.bind(this)}>
                            <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}


class AddContactPanel extends React.Component {
    handleAddContact(e) {
        var contactItem = this.refs.newContactName,
            r = this.refs;

        var cn = r.newContactName,
            co = r.newContactOccupation,
            ce = r.newContactEmail,
            ct = r.newContactTelephone;

        this.props.addNewContact({
            "id": (Math.random(1000 * 10) + 1),
            "name": cn.value,
            "occupation": co.value,
            "email": ce.value,
            "telephone": ct.value
        });

        cn.value = '',
            co.value = '',
            ce.value = '',
            ct.value = '';

        e.preventDefault();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <form>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <input required className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fullname" ref="newContactName" type="text" name="newContactName" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <input required className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Occupation" ref="newContactOccupation" type="text" name="newContactOccupation" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <input required className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email address" ref="newContactEmail" type="text" name="newContactEmail" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <input required className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Telephone" ref="newContactTelephone" type="text" name="newContactTelephone" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 text-right">
                        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-default icon btn-success btn-incentive btn-incentive--full-width" name="submit" onClick={this.handleAddContact.bind(this)} value="Add Contact" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = {
    contactListApp: ContactsListApp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ContactListPanel` tries to bind on `this.props.onUserInput`, which is not given as props inside your `ContactListsApp`. So in this case you are trying to bind(this) to an undefined function

This is your render function from the `ContactListApp`

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h3>
                    <i className="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Contact List
                </h3>
                <div className="contact-container">
                    <AddContactPanel addNewContact={this.addContact.bind(this)} />
                    <ContactListPanel contacts={this.state.data} deleteContact={this.deleteContact.bind(this)} updateContact={this.updateContact.bind(this)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

There you are only given `deleteContact` and `updateContact` as props to your `ContactListPanel`

However in your `ContactListPanel` you are assuming the function is there, and you are binding to it here:

```
class ContactListPanel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var delCont = this.props.deleteContact;
    var updCont = this.props.updateContact;
    var uInput = this.props.onUserInput; // <- this prop is undefined as far as I can see
    var items = Array.prototype.map.call(this.props.contacts, function (contact, index) {

        return <ContactItem
            key={index}
            id={contact.id}
            name={contact.name}
            occupation={contact.occupation}
            email={contact.email}
            telephone={contact.telephone}
            deleteContact={delCont.bind(this)}
            updateContact={updCont.bind(this)}
            onUserInput={uInput.bind(this)}
            />
    });
```

You can solve this in various ways. Either you define propTypes and say which properties are required (at least you would get the notification in your console saying that this property is missing, so you have some more type security in your component), or you could create local functions for your callback, and then check if the function is defined in the props and if so, call it, if not, handle it internally (or don't do anything at all)

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred in `app.min.js`, line 9, character 21230 ? really ?

You have to set up a correct development environment in order to get readable errors, you can't debug effectively without sourcemap files... if you are new and not able to configure your environment I suggest you to start with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) or any boilerplate.

Your first error is about this line in ContactListPanel

```
var items = Array.prototype.map.call(this.props.contacts, ...
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    this.props.contacts may be undefined
```

Comment: Icepickle was right although it did not solve my problem with onUserInput as it still persisted errors. In the end i used a this.state.inputValues object to store the state/values of the input values.